# Meaning of "per se"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I want the actual meaning of **"per se"**. I have found the definition as 
`"by/of/in itself"`

However, I am not getting this.

Here are some example sentences using this word. Can anyone replace the word in these sentences with simple English?

1. It is not the money **per se** that makes them unhappy, but the single-minded pursuit of that money.
2. It is not a pretty town **per se**, but it is where my family comes from, so I like it.
3. Research shows that it is not divorce **per se** that harms children, but the continuing conflict between parents.
4. There is no indication that just having a degree **per se** improves your chance of getting a job.

Comment: You've already pointed to a definition that gives you alternate wording: *by itself*, *of itself*, and *in itself*. Are you saying you don't understand what those three phrases mean?

Comment: @JasonBassford thank you for your interest. I have found my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [**by itself**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+itself) means

> Alone; **with nothing else added**.
>
> - One nail by itself won't hold up that picture frame—put another nail in on this side.
> - I think this dish is fine by itself—it doesn't need a sauce.

[**in itself**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+itself) is

> **Without the consideration of anything else**. (A shortening of the full phrase "in and of itself.")
>
> - The defendant's story seems plausible in itself, but when taken alongside the testimony of the witnesses, it starts to look less and less believable.
> - As a sequel, the movie does a good job of continuing the story of the first, but it fails as a cohesive, enjoyable film in itself.

[**of itself**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-itself-of-itself) is

> used for **emphasizing** that what you are saying about **one particular thing is true without even considering anything else**
>
> - Some of the medicines were out of date, which was in itself dangerous.
> - Using someone else’s name is not of itself a crime, unless there is an intention to commit a fraud.

The common thread in the definitions for "by/of/in itself" is

> **without considering/adding anything else**

Some synonyms for "[**per se**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/per%20se?s=t)" are

> - essentially
> - alone
> - as such
> - solely
> - independently

So, if you were to replace per se in your example sentences

> 1. It is not the money "**alone**" **(or only the money**) that makes them unhappy, but the single-minded pursuit of that money.
> 2. It is not a pretty town **as such**, but it is where my family comes from, so I like it.
>
>    - From what you see, the town is not pretty, but I like it because it's where my family comes from
> 3. Research shows that it is not divorce **essentially** that harms children, but the continuing conflict between parents.
>
>    - Research shows that the continuing conflict between parents harms children more than the fact that the parents got a divorce
> 4. There is no indication that just having a degree **alone** improves your chance of getting a job.
>
>    - There is no indication that if you just have a degree, your chances of getting a job are better

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elaborate explanation. It cleared all my doubts.

Comment: @Zaidur You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a *thing* itself and 'stuff' that is merely related to it, such as its *qualities*. For example, a *brick* as a 'thing' is a rectangular block of material. Its 'qualities' might include being *heavy* and being *rough to the touch*. You might also talk about things that are *made of* bricks such as *houses*. Talking about *roughness* and *houses* isn't the same thing as talking about the bricks themselves (i.e. they aren't the same as talking about bricks *per se*).

The phrase *per se* tends to be used within a negative phrase - "**not** talking about (X) *per se* but instead about (Y)". Here, X might be the brick and Y might be the house.

Let's consider your first example:

> It is not the money *per se* that makes them unhappy, but the single-minded pursuit of that money.

The 'thing' here is *money*. The quote says that it's not the money itself (*per se*) that makes them unhappy. It's something else (albeit related to money) that makes them unhappy - in this case, "the single-minded pursuit" of it.

**The term *per se* is used to explicitly focus on the thing itself rather than what is merely related to it.**

Comment: @Zaidur You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of the Latin is "through itself". *Per* has a range of meanings like any preposition but the basic meaning is "through".

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dper1

It takes the accusative so *se* is the accusative of *sui* meaning "himself","herself","itself","themselves", just like the word in French.

Comment: Thank you. Dictionaries doesn't contain this kind of breaking of the meaning.